# Reading settings from app.config in .net 4.5

Tags: c#, app-config

I've added a reference to System.Configuration. I've created App1.config in my project and populated it with the following code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <appSettings>
  <add key="ResistanceA" value="0.04"/>
  <add key="ResistanceB" value="0.04"/>
  <add key="ResistanceC" value="0.01"/>
  <add key="TempBattLow" value="40"/>
  <add key="TempBattHigh" value="45"/>
  <add key="TempLoad" value="40"/>    
 </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then I try to read the values using the following code,

```
using System.Configuration;

string str = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ResistanceA");
```

However I do not get the data. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Does the (app name here).config actually appear in the same folder as your (app name here).exe file?

Comment: For some reason I had two in there. App.config and the new one I created. It was trying to read from the first. Thanks for the easy solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the **(app name here).config** file actually appears in the same folder as your **(app name here).exe** file.  Being that you called it *App1.config*, I'm guessing that you have more than one.

Visual Studio renames App.Config to the actual (app name here).config file during a build, not App1.config.